# Click a button, wait and reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for some specific text on a page, then automatically clicking a button if the text exists (otherwise reloading the page after a few seconds). What I would like is to reload the page after the click has been executed (with a little delay). Here's my code which is not working:

```
var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var hasText = content.indexOf("this is my text")!==-1;
el = document.querySelector(".btn.secondClass");

if(hasText && el){
  el.click()
  {
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.location.reload()
    },5000);
  }
}
else {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.reload()
  },5000);
}
```

This just seems to reload the page after 5 seconds and the click doesn't get fired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Purpose of `jquery` tag???

Comment: what are you doing in the click

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d9tavLcv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.trigger` method to force a click. Use the following code:

```
var content = document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText;
var hasText = content.indexOf("this is my text") !== -1;
el = document.querySelector(".btn.secondClass");

$(el).click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 5000);
});

if (hasText && el) {
    $(el).trigger('click');

} else {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.reload()
    }, 5000);
}
```

Explanation: Bind your element's click event using `.click()`. Then check your condition and if satisfied, force the button to click using `.trigger()`. Since `el` is DOM node, to convert it to jquery object it must be wrapped by `$()`.

Comment: There is no `trigger()` DOM node method

Comment: But `el` is a DOM node object

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you're trying to achieve, you're redirecting after five seconds because that `setTimeout` call is always being made. You have an `if` statement but are including the `setTimeout` in both blocks. Why?

`setTimeout` takes either a string to evaluate or a callback function. Your callback function in this case is `window.location.reload` - you don't need to wrap it in another anonymous function. Use -

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
```

instead.

So your simplified code would be -

```
if (hasText && el) {
    el.click();
    setTimeout(window.location.reload, 5000);
}
```

with no `else` block.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (your condition = true) {
  setInterval(function() { 
    $(".btn.secondClass").trigger("click");
    window.location=""; 
  }, 5000);
}
      }
```